# Option to remove section from certain pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, show-hide

I am currently creating a wordpress site. Some pages will need a section with some images at the bottom and other pages won't. But this needs to be controlled via the backend

So when you go on that specific page in the wordpress backend, there will need to be a check box to decide whether to display the section or not.

It has to be this simple as my client is not tech savvy in the slightest.

Is there a plugin to maybe achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Danny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the Advanced Custom Fields [plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/). This way you can do a simple conditional along  the lines of `if(get_field('myCheckbox'){ // add your images };`

Further information can be found here: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/checkbox/

***Update in response to comment***

For a radio button, the code should be pretty similar - something like:

```
    $theField = get_field('name_of_radio_button_goes_here');
    if($theField == "enabled"){
        // THE HTML YOU WANT TO BE HIDDEN/SHOWN GOES HERE
    }
```

No need to add `display:none` or anything like that - unless "enabled" is selected for the page in Wordpress, then nothing will display for the page you are on

Comment: This could be what I'm looking for, ok I've set up a radio button with one called enabled and one called disabled. How would i write a statement to say:

If its set to enabled, set div to display:block
Else set div to display:none

thanks very much for your help so far :)

Comment: No problem - please see update. Hopefully that should be what you're after. Obviously you'll need to set the name of your field accordingly (i.e. replace "name_of_radio....." with the correct name of your field

Comment: I have managed to get it working, thanks very much for your help :)

Comment: Pleased to hear it - ACF is a great plugin :)